# Invalid Schema using schemaValidate of PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate xml files against a specific XSD with PHP. Tests have been done on Windows 7 with EasyPHP-12.1 (PHP 5.4.6 edition). Here is the server side PHP file which loads an xml, validates it and displays any errors.

**PHP code**

```
function libxml_display_error($error)
{
    $return = "<br/>\n";
    switch ($error->level) {
        case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
            $return .= "<b>Warning $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
            $return .= "<b>Error $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
            $return .= "<b>Fatal Error $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
    }
    $return .= trim($error->message);
    if ($error->file) {
        $return .=    " in <b>$error->file</b>";
    }
    $return .= " on line <b>$error->line</b>\n";

    return $return;
}

function libxml_display_errors() {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print libxml_display_error($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}

// Enable error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('testFile');
if (!$xml->schemaValidate('sampleSchema.xsd')) {
    print '<b>Errors Found!</b>';
    libxml_display_errors();
}
else {
echo "Validated Successfully!";
}
```

Using the below xml and xsd schema it works successfully without generating any errors:

**XML:**

```
 <lures>
     <lure>
      <lureName>Silver Spoon</lureName>
      <lureCompany>Clark</lureCompany>
      <lureQuantity>7</lureQuantity>
     </lure>
    </lures>
```

**XSD:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="lures">
     <xs:complexType> 
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="lure">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lureName" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="lureCompany" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="lureQuantity" type="xs:integer"/>
         </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

However, the problem appears when i try to validate a Mpeg7 xml according to the standard Mpeg7 schema file [mpeg7-v1.xsd](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-7_schema_files/mpeg7-v1.xsd), where PHP generates the following error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\ServerSideTests\validate.php on line 38
Errors Found!
Error 3008: local list type: A type, derived by list or union, must have the simple ur-type definition as base type, not '{urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001}integerVector'. in file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-12.1/www/ServerSideTests/mpeg7-v1.xsd on line 1251
```

I wonder how can be possible to be invalid the official XSD...since the XSD is perfectly correct, then maybe the libxml library is not fully compatible with this W3C Schema?
All i want to know is how i have to modify the above code for the succesfull validation of the mpeg7 files or if i have to implement it into another server side language...

**EDIT: My test Mpeg7 file**

```
<Mpeg7 xmlns="urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mpeg7="urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001" 
       xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001  mpeg7-v1.xsd">
<Description xsi:type="CompleteDescriptionType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Relationships/>
</Description>
</Mpeg7>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the XML needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lures xmlns="<THE NAME SPACE HERE"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://<SCHEMA NS LOCARTION - i.e. unique> lures\">
```

Then XSD needs

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="<SCHEMA NS LOCATION - as above>"
```

Comment: As i said, the XML and XSD i provide above they are validating without problem. The problem is that PHP cannot validate the standard mpeg7-v1.xsd while xml is properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lures xmlnshttp://nonwhere.com/"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://nowhere.com lures\">

 <lures>
     <lure>
      <lureName>Silver Spoon</lureName>
      <lureCompany>Clark</lureCompany>
      <lureQuantity>7</lureQuantity>
     </lure>
    </lures>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://nowhere.com">
    <xs:element name="lures">
     <xs:complexType> 
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="lure">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="lureName" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="lureCompany" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="lureQuantity" type="xs:integer"/>
         </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Seems to work for me. (that is PHP)

Comment: I already said that the xml and xsd u are reffering are working fine for me too. The problem is with the EDITED xml on my original when i try to validate it against the mpeg7-v1.xsd.

Comment: Supply the XSD then! Not the XSD you have given us.

Comment: Just click on mpeg7-v1.xsd on my original post, it links to that XSD.

Comment: @KostKont - Why post a different XSD? Besides cannot be bothered to do your job

Comment: I post the first XML and XSD to be clear that the problem is not at code, something u didnt got at all since u didnt read my original post at its whole...if u dont know the answer u could just leave it alone and not post irrelevant things like ur last post...

Comment: @KostKont - Guess a deadline is hitting hard. You did post the schema for comment then changed the goal posts. Good luck